# SQL Column Comparison

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have two queries I need in one table, and haven't been able to find results in searching. 
In the first table there is a UserID, which is a number, along with what the actual user id is and user's name.

My issue is that in every other query the user is only referred to as this number. I'm needing help in how to translate this UserID value into the actual User's name in my other queries.

Table with User's ID and User's Name:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table].[dbo].[User]
```

Table example where the user is only referred to as this number, along with all other tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table].[LoginStatus]
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables:

```
SELECT u.[UserName], l.*
FROM   [LoginStatus] l
JOIN   [Users] u ON u.id = l.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's just what I needed. I came across the JOIN function, but the instructions I was looking at didn't reference the 'ON' as you did.